# Ошибка синтаксиса (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, случайные-числа

Помогите исправить ошибку, данный код должен записывать в текстовый блокнот переменную rand, после чего test должен обновляться и переменная записываться заново в этот текстовый файл только с новой строчки.

код:

```
import random
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase
import os



with open("C:\test.txt", "w", ) as file:

def test():

    cs = random.randint(8,30)

    symbols = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_'
    rand = (''.join(choice(symbols) for i in range(cs)))
    file.write(f"{rand}\n") 
    print(rand)

    test()

test()
```

Comment: Какую ошибку вы получаете ?

Comment: ошибку синтаксиса в def test():

Comment: Всегда нужно вставлять в вопрос текст ошибки полностью. Для начала исправьте отступы в коде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы использовали `with` без тела внутри:

> `with open("C:\test.txt", "w", ) as file:`

Замените это на присваивание:

```
file = open(r"C:\test.txt", "w")
```

---

Еще у вас тут бесконечная рекурсия:

```
def test():
    ...

    test()

test()
```

Тут вообще не нужно рекурсивного вызова

---

Не понятно откуда `aa` берется в `range(aa)`, скорее всего там должно быть значение `cs`

---

Я бы рекомендовал значение из функции возвращать и результат записывать в файл:

```
def test() -> str:
    cs = random.randint(8,30)
    symbols = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_'
    return ''.join(choice(symbols) for _ in range(cs))

with open("C:\test.txt", "w", ) as file:
    rand = test()
    print(rand)
    file.write(f"{rand}\n")
```